# The difficulty is going to be finding enough supply to meet the demand

Tags: grammar

> The difficulty is going to **be finding** enough supply to meet the demand.
>   Source: *Skills for Success*, published by Oxford

I know after ***going to***  we need a simple verb but also I think it should've been like below

> The difficulty is going to **find** enough supply to meet the demand.

And also ***find*** is always a verb.

Are there more examples?

Comment: The first example is better, but you didn't group the phrase properly. "The difficulty is [**going to be**] finding enough supply to meet the demand." The **going to** in your first (better) phrase is about *difficulty* and not about *finding*.

Comment: "Find" is not always a verb (e.g. "the find of the century").

Comment: In the second sentence, it sounds like *the difficult* is the agency that's going to be doing the action of finding enough supply.

Comment: So, 'finding' here is an adjective? I dont think so bcz still I am in 'find' is always a verb

Comment: No, **finding** is a gerund there.

Answer (score 1):

The "going to be" refers to the difficulty.

"Finding" is a gerund here - it is connected to the simple verb "be", rather than as a phrase "be finding".

The sentence could be rephrased as:

> The difficulty is going to be: *how to find* enough (...)

Answer (score 1):

The original sentence:

> The difficulty is going to be finding enough supply to meet the demand.

The difficulty is going to be what? It's going to be **finding enough supply to meet the demand**. Treat the whole thing as a noun phrase. That's what the difficulty is going to be—finding enough supply to meet the demand. This is what the sentence looks like structurally:

> A is going to B.

Where **A** is **the difficulty** and **B** is **finding enough supply to meet the demand**. This is in principle the same thing as this:

> I'm going to be a police officer.

Where **A** is **I** and **B** is **a police officer**.

Now, let's make the example more closely resemble your original sentence:

> **The problem** is going to be **becoming a police officer**.

Though, I should warn you that the phrasing feels a little bit unnatural. It would be better to switch the order:

> Becoming a police officer is going to be the problem.
>
> Finding enough supply to meet the demand is going to be the difficulty.

---

Your second sentence:

> The difficulty is going to find enough supply to meet the demand.

It sounds like **the difficulty** is the entity that's going to do **the finding of enough supply to meet the demand**. But that makes no sense since **the difficulty** is not a person. So, to be perfectly honest, the sentence is not a good one.

Answer (score 0):

Something is a difficulty. What? A task. What task? The task of finding something. "Finding something" is a phrase that of which the grammatical function is the same as a noun.

The fact that the difficulty in is the future, means that it is described as a difficulty that is "going to be". Those words are another way in English of referring to the future.

So, what we have is: in the future, finding  enough, will be a difficulty.

Comment: I see, okay without 'be' it doesn't make enough sense. and it's a ground and also it's not a phrasal verb. Can you give me more example of this?

Answer (score 0):

The complement of **BE** can be a quality or condition:

**Is she going to BE *happy*?**

> The difficulty is going to be *evident*.
>
> The difficulty is going to be *insurmountable*.

The complement of **BE** can be a noun or nominal:

**She is going to BE *an astronaut*.**

Gerunds like **finding** have nominal status:

> The difficulty is going to be *finding a solution*.

***Finding enough money to pay the mortgage* is going to be the difficulty.**